# Merge and Zip with list comprehension

Tags: erlang, list-comprehension

Want to merge [1,3,4], [2,5] -> [1,2,3,4,5] and zip [1,2,3],[4,5] -> [{1,4},{2,5}]. Its not homework, i just want improve my skill in list-comprehensions. If you know any links to tricks with it, dont hesitate to submit.

Comment: Take a look at lists:merge/1 for the first problem. See answer below for the second.  None of them can be solved with list comprehensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
1> [1,3,4] ++ [2,5].
[1,3,4,2,5]
2> lists:zip([1,2],[4,5]).
[{1,4},{2,5}]
```

For the zip, you can also write your own:

```
% zip.erl
-module(zip).
-export([zip/2]).

zip(A, B) ->
    zip(A, B, []).

zip(_, [], Result) ->
    Result;

zip([], _, Result) ->
    Result;

zip([A|ARest], [B|BRest], Result) ->
    zip(ARest, BRest, [{A, B}|Result]).
```

Result:

```
8> c(zip).
{ok,zip}
9> zip:zip([1,2,3],[4,5]).  
[{2,5},{1,4}]
```

Comment: i mean list-comprehension approach, you know - [X || X <- L, ...]

Comment: and first have a trick, its a part of merge sort, so resulted array must be sorted.

Comment: @Yola - there is not such construct to make this using list comprehensions.

Comment: `zip([H1|T1], [H2|T2]) ->
 [{H1, H2} | [{X,Y} || {X,Y} <- zip(T1, T2)]];
zip(_, _) -> [].`

Comment: previous msg shown my approach with list-comprehension, but it looks redundant( and even ridiculously(

Comment: The list comprehension here is the identity function: `[{X,Y} || {X,Y} <- zip(T1, T2)]`